# How can I make addcontentsline jump to the correct position of chapter header?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I am trying to use `\addcontentsline` but I could not make it work correctly.
The link it produces either jumps to the page before or jumps over the chapter header, depending on where I put it.
Here is the MWE

```latex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A}
\lipsum[1]

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{B} %% <-- jumps to the page before
\chapter*{B}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{B} %% <-- jumps over the chapter header
\lipsum[2]

\chapter{C}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

I tried to put `\clearpage` or `\newpage` in front, but neither worked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a double sided document, so you need a `\cleardoublepage` so that the anchor from `\phantomsection` is on the right page. Alternatively you can also put it somewhere below the chapter and move it up, see the raisebox example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A}
\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage 
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{B} %% <-- jumps to the page before
\chapter*{B}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{B} %% <-- jumps over the chapter header

\raisebox{3cm}[0pt][0pt]{\phantomsection HERE}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{B} %% 

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{C}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```